# scipy hierarchical clustering returns strange results for over 100 datapoints

Tags: arrays, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I have started using SciPy hierarchical clustering with a 'handcrafted' condensed difference matrix and hit a strange issue. I expected the output in the form of the array in the following format

```
    array([
        [ind1, ind2, distance, no_of_elements_in_1st_cluster],
        [ind1, ind2, distance, no_of_elements_in_2nd_cluster],
        ...
    ])
```

e.g.

```
    array([
        [  48. ,   62. ,  0.5414134 ,    2.    ],
        [  27. ,   50. ,  0.55187726,    2.    ],
       ...
    ])
```

Things are just as expected up to 100 data points, but over it, I get an array of four floating point numbers instead, e.g.

```
    array([
    [  1.83000000e+02, 2.33000000e+02, 2.17551845e-01, 2.00000000e+00],
    [  2.52000000e+02, 2.54000000e+02, 2.39957465e-01, 2.00000000e+00],
      ...
    ]).
```

Strangely enough the array does include some values in the expected format, particularly towards the end of it.

I generate myself a 'condensed distance matrix' with combination(n,2) elements of distance values (I was not able to use pdist(x) function since I use a custom distance function) and feed this, let it be y, into the linkage method, i.e.

```
    scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(y, 'ward')
```

So with 100 datapoints namely 4950 values in the matrix, everything seems fine. With 101 (5050 values) everything breaks down (or so it seems).

With little experience in the module I don't know how to start trying to fix it. Anybody who had the same issue, or could see what's going on here? A help would be appreciated, plus I'd be happy to provide more info.

Cheers

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the output you are seeing? *"I get an array of four floating point numbers instead"* - `linkage` *always* returns an array of floats (including in your first example).

Comment: Also: *"I was not able to use pdist(x) function since I use a custom distance function"* - the `metric=` argument to `pdist` can also be a function implementing a custom distance metric.

Comment: As @ali_m pointed out, in both cases the result is an array of floats.  The only difference is that in the second case, some of the values are big enough that numpy changes that output format to exponential notation (i.e. `1.83000000e+02` instead of `183.`).

Comment: sure... very basic. I should have noticed. Thanks